# Mongoose delete element in array without deletion code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I send many push requests to specific array in my document via `mongoose` then I display this array by parsing json in my app, many object in this array was deleted or exchanged without any deletion code.

I have tried for more time but I didn't found a solution

Here is my code

```
exports.push = function(req, res) {
  var conditions = { _id: req.params.userId };

  User.updateOne(conditions, {
    $push: {
      user_history: {
        heart_Beat: req.body.heart_Beat,
      }
    }
  }).select()
    .exec(doc => {  
    if (!doc) {
      return res.status(409).end();
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'saved',
      result: doc
    })
  })   
}
```

And here my schema:

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  phoneNumber: { type: String, default: 0 },
  heartBeat: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  user_history: [
    {
      heart_Beat: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      date: { type: String, default: () => moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: You can post a sample input document; it will be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean by input document

Comment: I mean a sample document in the collection you are trying to update.

Comment: I post my schema , and I am trying to update user_history

Comment: Can you give example data which was not updated to the `user_history` array.

Comment: I am using rest api in my mobile app  , I get the value of heartBeat of my schema then put it into a variable then push to user_history every x of time  many of data is stored in the array suddenly I found the array contain only two or three  element  the old values have been removed from array

Comment: I don't know how the saved array is removed or replaced by newest one  , the array is disorder when many pushing requests happened